# SCOM OperationsManagerDW table details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sccm, sql-scripts

I am working on preparing a healthcheck report by pulling the details from OperationsManagerDW database in SCCM server. I need below details to be retrieved from OperationsManagerDW database. Could you please help me with the scripts. I see there is no straight forward way to pull these details from the tables.Basically i will provide the server name and timestamp, which would give me these details from OperationsManagerDW database.
1)Server details and status.
2)Database details and status.
3)CPU utilization.
4)Disk utilization
5)Memory utilization
6)Failed jobs
7)IO
8)Blockings

Thank you.

Comment: First, performance data in DW DB is stored in aggregated way, i.e. all samples within an hour are being aggregated into min/max/avg and deviation values. Next, it's unclear, if you need last disk utilization (for instance) reading, or a historical sequence for last X days. Finally, it's not an easy task: you need to find specific rules by counter names, then match rules ID to rule instance IDs, then locate perf data by computer instance ID and rule instance ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script I wrote in powershell can help you (its for SCOM):
[Invoke-SQL_DW_AgentPerformance](https://github.com/blakedrumm/SCOM-Scripts-and-SQL/blob/master/Powershell/Invoke-SQL_DW_AgentPerformance.ps1)

It gathers the Disk Space in MB, CPU Utilization, Free Disk Space Percentage, and Memory Percentage Used.